Determinant of a Permutation Matrix and Its Relationship with the Sign of a Permutation
Let $\sigma_0 \in S_n$, and let $A = (a_{i,j})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ be the matrix defined for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, by
$$
a_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } i = \sigma_0(j), \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
After giving the definition of the determinant of a square matrix involving the symmetric group, show that $\det(A) = \varepsilon(\sigma_0)$.
Hint: You can decompose the sum in the determinant into two sums...

See Permutation matrix. Besides, what is your work on this issue ?

@JeanMarie Thank you, can you give me more detailed reference please?

In the reference I gave, look for entry "determinant", the key point being the decomposition into elementary matrices.
